# Objective C - Instantiating Objects and Calling Methods with Multiple Parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

Hi I have the following class called CalculatorOperations:

```
#import "CalculatorOperations.h"

@implementation CalculatorOperations

+(float)add:(float)numOne with:(float)numTwo{
    return numOne + numTwo;
}
@end
```

I then try to call this class method as follows from within my Calculator class:

```
#import "Calculator.h"
#import "CalculatorOperations.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 

@implementation Calculator

+(float)add:(float)numOne to:(float)numTwo{
    CalculatorOperations *calcOp = [CalculatorOperations alloc];
    float answer = [calcOp add:numOne with:numTwo];
    return answer;
}

@end
```

The problem is I keep getting a "incompatible types in initialisation" message when trying to assign the return value of a the add:with method to a variable (answer).

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling a class method (the `+` indicates class method) on an instance of the class. In addition, you aren't `init`ing the class as required for an instance of that class.

Try this:

```
@implementation Calculator

+(float)add:(float)numOne to:(float)numTwo{
    return [CalculatorOperations add:numOne with:numTwo];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` means that is is a Class method not an instance method, change the methods to `-` to get it to be an instacne method.

```
 #import "CalculatorOperations.h"
 @implementation CalculatorOperations

- (float)add:(float)numOne with:(float)numTwo{
    return numOne + numTwo;
}
@end
```

Also you need to init the class:

```
#import "Calculator.h"
#import "CalculatorOperations.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 

@implementation Calculator

+(float)add:(float)numOne to:(float)numTwo{
    CalculatorOperations *calcOp = [[CalculatorOperations alloc] init];
    float answer = [calcOp add:numOne with:numTwo];
    return answer;
}

@end
```

Or change the call off the `(float)add:(float)numOne with:(float)numTwo` method:

```
@implementation Calculator

+(float)add:(float)numOne to:(float)numTwo{
    float answer =  [CalculatorOperations add:numOne with:numTwo];
    return answer;
}

@end
```

Damm I need to learn to type faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need....

```
CalculatorOperations *calcOp = [[CalculatorOperations alloc] init];
```

Plus your method is a class method (hence the +)...

```
float value = [CalculatorOperations add:1.0 with:2.0];
```

Comment: It still says the same thing?